# Constant 403 errors when trying to access mailman listinfo and admin in nginx

Tags: nginx, mailman

I've set up nginx and mailman (among everything else) via this tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4

I was able to successfully create a mailing list (called `braindexter-pre-registration`) and have received the welcome email, but whenever I try to access the admin page to add members or send an email, I get a (mostly) blank page that says `403`.

I get the error if I visit `http://192.168.1.12:8081/cgi-bin/mailman/admin/braindexter-pre-registration`, and if I visit `http://192.168.1.12/cgi-bin/mailman/admin/braindexter-pre-registration`, I just get the Welcome to nginx! screen.

Here is what my error log says when I use port 8081:

```
2013/07/24 19:10:35 [error] 12255#0: *32 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot chdir to script directory (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/admin)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.11, 
server: _, request: "GET /cgi-bin/mailman/admin/braindexter-pre-registration HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "192.168.1.12:8081"
```

Here is what my access log says when I use port 80:

```
192.168.1.11 - - [24/Jul/2013:19:12:31 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/mailman/admin/braindexter-pre-registration HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
```

I am completely stumped here as to how to proceed. I have tried following the suggestions in http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,227508,227508#msg-227508 but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.